# CiviCRM cron job not processing scheduled jobs

Tags: civimail, cron-job

CiviCRM 4.6.0

I have tried setting up the cron job to process the mailing scheduled job using both the php cli method and the URL with wget.

In the first case, I can get the cli.php to run from the command line and the mail queue is processed but when I try to run the same job from cron, it fails with an invalid username and/or password error. The username and password are exactly as specified when run from the command line (copied and pasted).

With the URL method, I cannot get the job to process the queue either from the command line or from the cron job. The mail remains in the queue.

The cron jobs are being set up in the CPanel.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a character in your password that needs to be URL-encoded?  Like an ampersand, perhaps?

Comment: Did you check the permissions http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviMail+Installation#CiviMailInstallation-CMSUserandRole ?

Comment: The password has no characters that need to be URL encoded

Comment: Permissions are okay.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on drupal for the CMS? in that case, using the drush option is easier to set up than the cli.php in my experience (you don't have to give credentials, and in general, deals better with the authentication of the cron user)

Comment: This is a Joomla site.

Answer (score 1):

I used the example for "Using the shell (CLI PHP) via Crontab" and got that to work so this can be closed.

I really don't know what else I can say. I used the sample script for "Using the shell (CLI PHP) via Crontab", set up the parameters correctly and it worked

Comment: Can you detail what you did to make it work (and maybe copy paste the relevant points in the wiki) and accept your answer to close the question (by accepting your answer, you close the question)

Comment: Agree that saying what you did, linking to the instructions, and accepting this answer is what's needed to "close" this. @Vietyank can you please update this answer with those things?